# ActivityNotFoundException exception on Jelly Bean for Gmail composer

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean

This class works fine on ICS, but fails with `ActivityNotFoundException` on Jelly Bean. Do you guys know why? Thank you.

```
public class EmailSender {

    public static Intent getSendEmailIntent(Context context, String email,
                                            String subject, String body, File fileName, String chooserTitle) {

        final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(
                android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

        //Explicitly only use Gmail to send
        emailIntent.setClassName("com.google.android.gm", "com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivityGmail");

        emailIntent.setType("plain/text");

        //Add the recipients
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                new String[]{email});

        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);

        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);

        //Add the attachment by specifying a reference to our custom ContentProvider
        //and the specific file of interest
        emailIntent.putExtra(
                Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                Uri.fromFile(fileName));

        return emailIntent;
    }
}
```

On Jelly Bean I'm getting an exception:

> 11-19 15:32:07.852: E/AndroidRuntime(19630):
>   android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit
>   activity class
>   {com.google.android.gm/com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivityGmail};
>   have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Full trace in case of need:

> 11-19 15:32:07.852: E/AndroidRuntime(19630):
>   android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit
>   activity class
>   {com.google.android.gm/com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivityGmail};
>   have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml? 11-19
>   15:32:07.852: E/AndroidRuntime(19630):    at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1618)
>   11-19 15:32:07.852: E/AndroidRuntime(19630):  at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)
>   11-19 15:32:07.852: E/AndroidRuntime(19630):  at
>   android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3370) 11-19
>   15:32:07.852: E/AndroidRuntime(19630):    at
>   android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3331) 11-19
>   15:32:07.852: E/AndroidRuntime(19630):    at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityFromFragment(FragmentActivity.java:701)
>   11-19 15:32:07.852: E/AndroidRuntime(19630):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:787) 11-19
>   15:32:07.852: E/AndroidRuntime(19630):    at
>   ebeletskiy.gmail.com.passwords.ui.Export.sendByEmail(Export.java:91)
>   11-19 15:32:07.852: E/AndroidRuntime(19630):  at
>   ebeletskiy.gmail.com.passwords.ui.Export.access$400(Export.java:22)
>   11-19 15:32:07.852: E/AndroidRuntime(19630):  at
>   ebeletskiy.gmail.com.passwords.ui.Export$1.onClick(Export.java:57)
>   11-19 15:32:07.852: E/AndroidRuntime(19630):  at
>   android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202) 11-19 15:32:07.852:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(19630):  at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340) 11-19
>   15:32:07.852: E/AndroidRuntime(19630):    at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725) 11-19
>   15:32:07.852: E/AndroidRuntime(19630):    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 11-19
>   15:32:07.852: E/AndroidRuntime(19630):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 11-19 15:32:07.852:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(19630):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039) 11-19
>   15:32:07.852: E/AndroidRuntime(19630):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 11-19
>   15:32:07.852: E/AndroidRuntime(19630):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 11-19 15:32:07.852:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(19630):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>   11-19 15:32:07.852: E/AndroidRuntime(19630):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 11-19
>   15:32:07.852: E/AndroidRuntime(19630):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: The compose activity possibly changed names in the 4.2 version? Is there a reason you need to specifically use gmail and can't just use a general email intent?

Comment: No, I don't have a strong reason to use GMail indeed.

Comment: I'd advise against doing so. Using such a strict intent means that the user needs to have gmail installed to use your app. Not everybody uses gmail for their mail client.. additionally, by hardcoding class names you leave yourself open to instances where the class name changes can result in your activity breaking

Comment: i checked and in the 4.2 version the class is com.android.mail.compose.ComposeActivity

Comment: @dymmeh, thanks, please give an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd advise against using an intent to directly open the gmail compose activity. Using such a strict intent means that the user needs to have gmail installed to use your app. Not everybody uses gmail for their mail client.. Additionally, by hardcoding class names you leave yourself open to instances where the class name changes can result in your activity breaking (which is the cause of your current problem)

I decompiled the gmail 4.2 application and found that the ComposeActivity class name and path has changed.. it is now `com.android.mail.compose.ComposeActivity`

You should use a general email intent that allows the user to use the email application of their choosing

Comment: isn't there a way of sending the email without specifying this classname? intent.setClassName("com.google.android.gm", "com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivityGmail");

Answer (score 0):

Look closer at this line

have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml

Perharps you just didn't have the activity declared.

Comment: Yes, I have this activity declared in my AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Did you try ACTION_VIEW instead of ACTION_SEND ?